# JQuery If(current page === something)

Tags: jquery

I would want JQuery code like that

```
if (current page === something) {
    $("div").AddClass("active")
}
```

How to do it?

This is because i'm using bootstrap, so it isn't allowing me to make :active selector.

I want effect like that under text:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDnzc.jpg

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

**HTML**

```
<div id="pageid" value="landing">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var page = $('#pageid').attr('value');
alert(page);
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1p8j2a8f/)

Comment: And, how could it help me? I want it to detect page , like index.html

Comment: in the value field, add a page id/name or whatever you like to distinguish this page from the others.

Answer (score 0):

`location.href` contains the URL of the current page. So

```
if (location.href == something) {
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

You can also use `location.pathname` to just get the pathname part of the URL.

```
if (location.pathname == '/index.html') {
    $("div").addClass("active");
}
```

If you don't want to match the directory part explicitly, you can write:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf('pluginview.html') != -1) {
    $("#pluginviewbody").hide();
}
```

Comment: @LoganMaster No difference in this case.

Comment: `location.pathname` is the whole path, including all the directory prefixes.